# fail to install spyder-kernels

Tags: python, spyder

After selecting a python interpreter within spyder I get the following error (in spyder):

> The Python environment or installation whose interpreter is located at
> C:\ProgramData~
>
> doesn't have the spyder‑kernels module or the right version of it
> installed (>= 2.4.0 and < 2.5.0). Without this module is not possible
> for Spyder to create a console for you.
>
> You can install it by activating your environment first (if necessary)
> and then running in a system terminal:
> conda install spyder-kernels=2.4 or
> pip install spyder-kernels==2.4.*

When I go to pip install spyder-kernels==2.4.1 I get the following error:

> Collecting spyder-kernels==2.4.1   Using cached
> spyder_kernels-2.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (97 kB) ERROR: Could not
> find a version that satisfies the requirement ipython<9,>=7.31.1;
> python_version >= "3" (from spyder-kernels) (from versions: 0.10,
> 0.10.1, 0.10.2, 0.11, 0.12, 0.12.1, 0.13, 0.13.1, 0.13.2, 1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 2.0.0, 2.1.0, 2.2.0, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 3.0.0, 3.1.0, 3.2.0, 3.2.1, 3.2.2, 3.2.3, 4.0.0b1, 4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.0.3, 4.1.0rc1, 4.1.0rc2, 4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.1.2, 4.2.0, 4.2.1, 5.0.0b1, 5.0.0b2, 5.0.0b3, 5.0.0b4, 5.0.0rc1, 5.0.0, 5.1.0, 5.2.0, 5.2.1, 5.2.2, 5.3.0, 5.4.0, 5.4.1, 5.5.0, 5.6.0, 5.7.0, 5.8.0, 5.9.0, 5.10.0, 6.0.0rc1, 6.0.0, 6.1.0, 6.2.0, 6.2.1, 6.3.0, 6.3.1, 6.4.0, 6.5.0, 7.0.0b1, 7.0.0rc1, 7.0.0, 7.0.1, 7.1.0, 7.1.1, 7.2.0, 7.3.0, 7.4.0, 7.5.0, 7.6.0, 7.6.1, 7.7.0, 7.8.0, 7.9.0, 7.10.0, 7.10.1, 7.10.2, 7.11.0, 7.11.1, 7.12.0, 7.13.0, 7.14.0, 7.15.0, 7.16.0, 7.16.1, 7.16.2, 7.16.3) ERROR: No matching distribution found for ipython<9,>=7.31.1; python_version >= "3"

Does anyone know how I resolve this?

Comment: If the Python interpreter you want to use is in an environment, rebuild the environment including `spyder-kernels` in the requirements.

Comment: …see also http://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/troubleshooting/common-illnesses.html#spyder-kernels-version-ref